# How to add horizontal/vertical scrollbars to JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I want to add horizontal scrollbars to my JScrollPane, because my table right now looks like the one below:

[image]

Here is my code to create the table:

```
  this.table = new JTable();
  this.table.setShowGrid(false);
  this.table.getTableHeader().setFont(ReportViewConstants.TABLE_FONT);
  this.table.setFont(ReportViewConstants.TABLE_FONT);

  this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.table);
  Dimension size = new Dimension(300, 400);
  this.scrollPane.setPreferredSize(size);
  this.scrollPane.setMinimumSize(size);
  this.scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

Can you point out what I'm doing wrong? When I changed the line to create a JScrollPane to:

```
  this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.table,
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

The scrollbars are there, but I still cannot scroll horizontally. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set for [JTable#setAutoResizeMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoResizeMode%28int%29), more is described in `JTable's` tutorial [Setting and Changing Column Widths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width)

Comment: +1 for the auto resize mode. The default is to force the columns to fit in the space provided.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
Dimension tableSize = new Dimension(500, 400);
this.table.setPreferredSize(tableSize);
```

Comment: -1, in general you should not use the setPreferred size on any component. You should definitely not set the preferred size of a component that you add to a scroll pane since the scrollbars will not dynamically appear as you add/remove rows/columns from the table.