# table headers not showing up on top of table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jtableheader

I am making a JTable and I am having 2 problems. #1 the table headers are showing up on the side of the table and #2 the scroll pane isn't showing up. This is some of my code right now.

```
String [] data = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
JFrame frame = new JFrame("String Table");
JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();              
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
model.addColumn("String", data);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);    


frame.getContentPane().add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
middlePanel.add(scrollPane);
middlePanel.add(table.getTableHeader());
middlePanel.add(table);


frame.setSize(400, 200);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use only code line `middlePanel.add(scrollPane);`
2. `JPanel (middlePanel)` should be layed by `GridLayout` or `BorderLayout`
3. remove code lines `middlePanel.add(table.getTableHeader());` and `middlePanel.add(table);`
4. move code line `frame.getContentPane().add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);` after `middlePanel.add(scrollPane);`, and could be `frame.add(middlePanel);` if isn't changed `LayoutManager` for `JFrame`
5. remove `frame.setSize(400, 200);` replace with `frame.pack()` and to determine proper `PreferredSize` by override `getPreferredSize` for `JScrollPane`

Comment: I ran into another issue. My table is showing up really small and the elements in the first column are quite long, so I need to extend both the table and column 1

Comment: more ideas about to see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10089138/714968) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9164884/714968)